# What's an easy way to deal with disabled cookies on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

I've bumped into several users that have cookies disabled and therefore the site doesn't work like I'd want.  I'm using webapp2 and django 1.2 templates with {% url %} template tags on appengine.

I'd like to find an easy way to address this that doesn't make me end up making LOTS of code changes.  Going to all my urls and conditionally adding ?cookie= to all of them is going to be a real pain, so I'm hoping there is a simple solution to this problem.

It causes problems with the CSRF code on forms too, what do you do in that case, just give up CSRF?

I can do some stuff in the urlNode code since I should be able to resolve the logged_in_user object from the context, so that might deal with a good bit of the problem, except any place that adds params after the ? will now have to use &.  All in all, NOT a pretty solution.

Anyone know of an easier way to deal with this?

Comment: You haven't explained what you need cookies for. Is it just for session management? Something else?

Comment: Yea, the cookies are for session management, it's a FB app, so I don't necessarily have Google Accounts for the users.  The only things I'm storing in the cookies are the CSRF stuff and the user session keys.  What else could I use the cookies for?

Comment: If your users have cookies disabled, a huge fraction of the web is going to be broken for them, including most other sites that require authentication. Tell them to get a grip and re-enable cookies, or stop worrying about them - they're a tiny, tiny, paranoid minority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommended building site with cookies as optional requirement, site design gets soon extremely complicated and you probably open more security holes that you can imagine. If you must support users without cookies, use HTTP basic authentication to authenticate and recognize users.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this idea either.